# Archiving salesforce records

Tags: force.com, activities, archive

I am looking to understand what happens to the archived records in Salesforce. Will they still be reportable? Other than reportability what are other characteristics of archived records? Can I save space by marking records as Archived in Salesforce?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After Salesforce archives activities, you can view them in **exported** data and in certain locations in **Salesforce Classic**. Activities are archived regardless of whether you use Salesforce Classic, Lightning Experience, or Salesforce1. However, although you can view archived activities in exported data and in Salesforce Classic, **you can’t view them in Lightning Experience or Salesforce1**.

You can view archived activities in these locations.

> **Viewing Archived activities**

1. In Salesforce Classic, by clicking View All in the Activity History
   related list
2. In Salesforce Classic, in the printable view of the
   record in the Name or Related To field
3. By using the URL for the
   activity, if you know it
4. In weekly data export files

for details, kindly review this [aricle](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=activities_archived_displayed.htm&type=0).

> **Deleting Archived activites**

First, **export** archived activities by following these steps:

1. Click on the **Export All** button (the *Export* button will not work in
   this particular case)
2. Select Tasks or Events
3. Select the Id field and other desired fields for export and set a
   condition filter: IsArchived Equals TRUE
4. Click on Add Condition
5. Finish

Now, the resulting file will contain the Ids for archived activities which you can use then use to perform a **delete** operation with Data Loader.

Comment: Does archiving records reduces the storage consumption ?

Comment: I **don't** think so. Archived records can still be accessed using data loader or [`queryAll()`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_queryall.htm#topic-title). Archived records reside in the object with `isArchived` field set to `True`.

Comment: So if you are looking to save storage, you can export the data and take back up. Then `delete` the **archived records** using delete procedure explained above.